# Missing Filesize in FAT32

Tags: filesystems, fat32

I have a .fat32 file and from the Master Boot Record I read the following things:

- 512 Bytes per Sector
- 8 Sectors per Cluster
- 800 Sectors total
- root Clusternumber is 2
- 32 reserved Sectors
- 2 FATs
- 1 Sector per FAT

800 sectors × 512 Bytes = 400kiB

When i check in the terminal with `df -Bk ./` then I get 380k.

So where did the 20kiB or 40 Sectors go?

I guessed that the 32 reserved Sectors before the FATs are part of them, but still 8 missing.

I then thought of the FATs themselves, so another 2×1 Sectors, but still 6 left.

I can't think of anything else but some weird theories and I'm not sure if they are correct:

- even before the reserved Sectors there is still space left (is the boot Sector part of the reserved sectors?) Or unused space at the very end?
- if any cluster is written into it is "full". So are the FATs part of a cluster and the 6 remaining sectors of that cluster are the 6 I'm missing? But directly after the FATs was the root cluster so means that, that the FATs are the last 2 sectors of their cluster?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> - 512 Bytes per Sector
> - 8 Sectors per Cluster
> - 800 Sectors total
> - root Clusternumber is 2
> - 32 reserved Sectors
> - 2 FATs
> - 1 Sector per FAT

32 reserved sectors, 2 FAT sectors leaves 800 - 34 = 766 sectors for data area.

766 mod 8 = 6, so there's 6 more we need to substract (as we can not have a partial cluster).

This leaves us with 760 addressable sectors or 95 (760 / 8) clusters of 4 KB = 380 KB.

Last 6 sectors of the partition aren't used by the file system.

Comment: thx I was wondering where the last 6 where on the disk :)

Comment: You could hide stuff there ;)